# “When did you born?”

Tags: idioms, questions

> When did you born?

What does the above question mean? Does it mean

1. "When did you give birth" or
2. "When were you given birth to"?

The situation is that I'm trying to ask my friend his birthdate.

Also, how can he answer this question in a grammatically correct way?

Comment: Two million results on Google. And guess which one is in the first place. The one you closed ;)

Comment: @Em1: exactly. That is *the* reason I am posting it here.

Comment: @Em1 And the second hit is *this* question now.

Answer (score 21):

> *When **did** you born?*

is not a grammatical sentence, because *born* is the past participle of the verb *to bear*, whereas you must use the bare infinitive after *did*.

The verb *to bear* means *to generate* among other things, so your question can be correcty asked using a passive form,

> *When **were** you born?*

which is equivalent to, but much more frequent than, *When were you given birth to?"

If your friend wants to answer this question in a grammatically correct way, they should answer *I was born on ...*

Comment: +1 Paola, there is also a famous film titled "When Were You Born" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/When_Were_You_Born

Comment: A woman bears a child.  A child is born by his mother, or is simply born.  After all, we all know who does the bearing.  (It isn't the child!)  This is why "to be born" is always in the passive voice when referring to the child, and in the active voice when referring to the mother.

Answer (score 4):

Judging by the context of results from the first few pages of a [Google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22When+did+you+born%3F%22&hl=en&tbo=d&ei=se4HUYWCPJCWjALBhYHQAg&start=10&sa=N&biw=1600&bih=785#q=%22When+did+you+born%3F%22&hl=en&tbo=d&ei=7-4HUfqyAsvwiQLdp4GwBg&start=0&sa=N&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&bvm=bv.41642243,d.cGE&fp=d2a8b5d92e947082&biw=1600&bih=785), it appears to mean (2), *"When were you given birth to?"*.

The grammatically correct form of this question is *"When were you born?"*. Additionally, your friend can answer with something like, *"I was born on January 29, 2013."*, with his actual birthday instead of today's date.

Answer (score 1):

The correct construction is "When *were* you born?" It's a "passive" construction because a new-born baby is "done to." Therefore,

Its meaning is 2) "When were you given birth to?"

Given that you referred to your friend as "he", number 1 is basically impossible: "When did you give birth?" (Unless it's a case where a man became a "surrogate mother," which I believe is actually possible.)

The grammatically correct answer is, "I was born *on* [date of birth].

Answer (score 0):

> When were you born?

and

> When did you give  birth?

Comment: Welcome to ELL.SE. it isn't clear which of your examples means which, however; please [edit] it to be more explicit.